# Linear independence over $\Bbb Z$ to prove an abstract algebra problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Show that there exists a subgroup of $\Bbb R$ that is isomorphic to $\Bbb ℤ \times \Bbb ℤ$.

I am instructed to consider "linear independece over $\Bbb Z$" in this problem, but I have no idea what this means? What I thought was that I needed to find a homomorphism $\eta: \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$ for which $\ker(\eta)=0$ so that $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z /\ker(\eta) \cong \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \cong \text{Im}(\eta)$.

Apparently this kind of homomorphism can be fonud using the "linear independece over $\Bbb Z$". Could I have a explanation on what does this mean in practice?

Comment: What is the set of vectors that you want to prove linear independence of?  In that case it's just the same thing as in vector spaces, except your coefficients are integers, not members of $k$ a field.

Comment: Do you understand why $(a,b) \rightarrow a + bi$ is a vector space isomorphism? Same idea but you replace $i$ with any irrational real number.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I don't unfortunately. It's been a while since I had any linear algerba. I assume you mean that this is a isomorphism between $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z[i]$?

Comment: @SleepWalker exactly. You have two integer coordinates in both cases. Here are three ways to write the same vector over different vector spaces $(a,b,c), ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3, a + bx + cx^2$. The first is our usual notation, the second is as a linear functional, and the third is over the space of quadradic single variable polynomials. Can you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: Not quite yet. You seem to be considering the vector in different bases? This supposedly has something to do with the fact that we can get vector space isomorphisms by mapping basis elements to basis elements?

Comment: @SleepWalker they're entirely difference vector spaces but they're all isomorphic when defined over the same base field. Despite these seeming complications, it's basically just notation. We have a first, second, and third position where we put the values of $a,b$ and $c$. Tuples, subscript or superscript notation doesn't make any meaningful mathematical difference between them. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hint: what is $z_1 + z_2\pi + \zeta_1 + \zeta_2\pi$, where $z_1,z_2,\zeta_1,\zeta_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField That makes sense!

Comment: @William It is $z_1 + \zeta_1 + (z_2 + \zeta_2)\pi$?

Comment: @SleepWalker Precisely. Do you see how this gives an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \{z_1 + z_2 \pi : z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\} \leq \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets look at the structure of homomorphisms (they are in a sense just like linear transformations)

(see that: $<a, 0> = \sum_{n=1}^{a} <1, 0> $)

$$ (<a,b>) = (<a,0>) + (<0,b>) =  (\sum_{n=1}^{a}<1,0> )+ (\sum_{n=1}^{b}<0,1> ) $$ $$ =\sum_{n=1}^{a} (<1,0>) + \sum_{n=1}^{b} (<0,1>)$$
$$ = a*(<1,0>) + b*(<0,1>)$$

lets say (<1,0>) = $c_1$ and (<0,1>) = $c_2$ ($c_1,c_2 \in ℝ$)

So we know $(<a,b>) = a c_1 + b c_2$
(Notice this as a linear combination -- you may even want to try and describe this as a matrix)

Now for such a homomorphism to have a kernel (well one that is not the trivial group)
$$ac_1 + bc_2 = 0$$
$$ac_1 = -bc_2$$
$$c_1 = \frac{-b}{a}c_2$$
this shows us that $c_1,c_2$ can be made from rational multiples of each other (they are in a sense linearly dependent)

Now if we pick $c_1, c_2$ such that they are not rational multiples of each other (in that sense linearly independent) then no kernel will exist.

This is quite easy as an irrational number ($c_1$) can not be a rational multiple of a rational number ($c_2$)

so if $c_1 \not \in \mathbb{Q}, c_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$

then
$(<a,b>) = ac_1 + bc_2$ ($a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$) will have $\ker() = \{0\}$

This idea of linear independence and vector spaces with the real numbers (and any other field for that matter) is a core idea of field extensions and very worth looking into.

A good next step is to generalize for $:\mathbb{Z}^{n}→\mathbb{R}$, which leads to a very important idea about a certain higher idea of numbers being linearly dependent (Think the difference between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$).

I hope I was able to help some.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that e.g. the real numbers $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$, in the sense that there don't exist $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, not both zero, such that $c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sqrt{2} = 0$ (because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational). This is a standard usage of the term 'linearly independent', even though of course you can't have a *vector space* over $\mathbb{Z}$, but the analogy with linear independence in vector spaces is obvious.

Anyway, this precisely means that the homomorphism $(m,n) \mapsto m + n\sqrt{2}$ has zero kernel, which is what you need.

Comment: I think this would work even if $c_i \in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: Correct, so this would also give a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with zero kernel.

Comment: That's just a different way of describing the same homomorphism - "map $(1,0)$ to $1$ and $(0,1)$ to $\sqrt{2}$". The important point is that the linear independence gives you zero kernel (or if you use the generators idea, it gives you full rank, as the image is spanned by 2 linearly independent elements, so is 2-dimensional like $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is. And that in turn gives zero kernel by rank-nullity.

Comment: @SleepWalker you can use $c_i \in \mathbb{F}$ for any field $\mathbb{F}$. What matters is that you can recover the coordinate from the index $i$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Are you sure? For $c_1, c_2 \in \Bbb R$ I think the equation $c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sqrt{2} = 0$ has solutions other than $c_1 = c_2  = 0$?

Comment: @SleepWalker that's right because you can't recover the two coordinates as they're not longer well-defined. This is because of things like $c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sqrt{2} = c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sqrt{2}/2 + c_2 \cdot \sqrt{2}/2=(c_1 + c_2 \cdot \sqrt{2}/2) \cdot 1 + c_2\cdot \sqrt{2}/2)$ which leads to ambiguity in both coordinates coordinate. You can however have $c_i$ for $i \in I$ for any indexing set $I$ and turn it into a vector space by defining the operations component-wise. As long as can project back onto the index it works.

Answer (score 2):

Linear independence over $\mathbb{Z}$ is really the same as linear independence over $\mathbb{Q}$, at least in this context: let $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $m\alpha + n\beta = 0$ for some integers $m,n$ implies $m=n=0$, meaning we have linear independence over $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose next $x\alpha + y\beta = 0$ for some rationals $x,y$: then we may multiply by a common denominator $d$ such that $dx,dy$ are integers, and obtain $dx \alpha + dy \beta = 0$, which implies $dx=dy=0$ by the assumption of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear independence, and therefore $x=y=0$. (The converse is trivial.)

So the question becomes: what does it mean for the images $\eta((1,0))$ and $\eta((0,1))$ to be $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent? Hint: it has something to do with irrationality.

Comment: How do you draw the conclusion that the question becomes "what does it mean for the images $\eta((1,0))$ and $\eta((0,1))$ to be $\Bbb Q$-linearly independent?" I think that this has something to do with the generators of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ being $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: Yes - and the point is that if you map those to elements of $\mathbb{R}$ that are linearly independent (over $\mathbb{Z}$), then the resulting homomorphism will have zero kernel.

Comment: @Prasiortle Why is it due to them being the generators of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ that results in the zero kernel homomorphism? As every homomorphism is completely determined by where it sends generators?

Comment: Yes. Because the homomorphism is determined by what it does to the generators, the image will be precisely the linear span of whatever the generators get mapped to. And the linear span of two linearly independent elements will give an image of dimension $2$ (the same as the domain), so zero kernel.